# minimee v2 and ee2 caching

Tags: cache, caching, cache-breaking

I am using expressionengine 2 and trying to compress css and js files, i can see the cached in the cache folder on my site root folder but the site does not display, it keeps loading. 
has there been anyone with this issue, are there any other alternatives for doing the above without slowing down the site.

thanks

Comment: I had this when I was trying to merge libraries with my own CSS/JS. Try limiting what is included in Minimee initially, especially just try CSS first, then JS, then widening it until it breaks - you may find you need to group them into multiples or re-order them instead of all in one. I avoided minimee in the end and do all the minifying and merging via my IDE (PHPStorm) upon saving.

Comment: will definitely look at the phpstorm option, sounds like a better option. will let you know if all goes welll

Comment: Have you tried to download the file yourself? Have you checked the HTML to see if it's pointing to the right file?

Answer (score 0):

I’d agree with Peter - start by breaking up the Minimee calls to give you lots of little minimee downloads: depending on how much stuff you have, maybe even try doing one per item to begin with.  Once you have done this, you can exploit the `queue / display` feature to stack up more than one entry to see how combinging them works.  For example:

`{exp:minimee:css queue="header”}
… css stuff … 
{/exp:minimee:css}
…other stuff…
{exp:minimee:css queue="header”}
… more css stuff … 
{/exp:minimee:css}
… other stuff …
{exp:minimee:display css="header”}`

will give you a single block of minimsed CSS cached by minimee that combines the two ‘header’ queues entries.

Useful documentation here - http://johndwells.github.io/Minimee/

HTH